# ¿Como usar TGpsStatus.SatelliteCount?

Tags: delphi, gps, delphi-tokyo

Hola buenas tardes a todos estoy intentando obtener el numero de satélites con los cuales se obtuvo un punto especifico en el GPS en Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Mi programa simplemente captura la latitud y la longitud con el componente `TLocationSensor` y su evento `onLocationChanged`.  Se que existe una clase llamada `TGpsStatus` la cual tiene la función `SatelliteCount` y que es la función que necesito usar; el problema es que no se como usarla, ya intente de todo y no consigo un buen reslutado, solamente obtengo el mensaje

> "Abstract Error"

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a guardar el numero de satélites con los que fue obtenido un punto del gps?, espero me puedan ayudar un poco.

Saludos y Gracias por su ayuda.!!

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he podido ver, calificaría como BUG la implementación de las clases `TGpsStatus`/`TPlatformGpsStatus`, por lo que al llamar a `TPlatformGpsStatus.Current`, que debiera devolver la clase específica de la plataforma en que se esté ejecutando el código, resulta en un EAbstractError, pues se referencia al método abstracto GetCurrent.

Sin embargo, se puede dar vuelta fácilmente al asunto utilizando una clase interpuesta. El siguiente código te mostrará la cantidad de satélites. El *inconveniente* es que es específico para una plataforma. (en el código de ejemplo, es Windows), aunque podría adaptarse para funcionar con distintas plataformas utilizando `{$ifdef}`.

```
uses
  System.Win.Sensors;

{$R *.fmx}

type
  TMyPlatformGpsStatus = class(TPlatformGpsStatus)
  public
    class function GetGpsStatusImplementer: TGpsStatusClass; override;
  end;

{ TMyPlatformGpsStatus }

class function TMyPlatformGpsStatus.GetGpsStatusImplementer: TGpsStatusClass;
begin
  Result := inherited;
end;

{TForm1}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Format('GPS con %d satélites', [TMyPlatformGpsStatus.GetGpsStatusImplementer.SatelliteCount]));
end;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, me podrías ayudar a que este código funcione para la plataforma Android, ya que es en donde necesito implementarlo, espero me puedas ayudar muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Kenneth, no tengo a mano un compilador para Android, pero en teoría, debiera funcionar si cambias el uses de `System.Win.Sensors` a `System.Android.Sensors` (lo digo de memoria, pero puedes verificarlo en tu instalación local). Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo intente con System.Android.Sensors y me sigue regresando "Abstract Error" mira deja hago un ejemplo sencillo para mostrarte mi código.